# Pandas fpr python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a excel file with some 2018-19 data, dates in d/m/y format are present for each data but I want to generate a crosstab between one type and year(year only not date) how can I do that?

I used this:

```
# generate crosstab of TYp and QN Created date
pd.crosstab(data_BM["Typ"],data_BM["QN Crtd",strftime('%d-%b-%y')])
```

Result I got:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-01be21abf4c1> in <module>
      1 # generate crosstab of TYp and QN Created date
----> 2 pd.crosstab(data_BM["Typ"],data_BM["QN Crtd",strftime('%d-%b-%y')])

NameError: name 'strftime' is not defined
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you get comes from an incorrect usage of `strftime` which is actually a [function](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html). You cannot use `strftime` in that way (and in general you **can not** include arguments inside the `[]` while indexing/slicing a DataFrame).

To use `strftime` you first have to convert your data (in this case a `Pandas.Series`) to the [`datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas.to_datetime) format like this:

```
import pandas as pd

data_BM["QN Crtd"] = pd.to_datetime(data_BM["QN Crtd"])
pd.crosstab(data_BM["Typ"], data_BM["QN Crtd"].dt.strftime('%d-%b-%y'))
```

This will cure the error you reported, not sure if it will let you do the `crosstab` thing.

Comment: yup the error is not there but the crosstab problem of year only is there.

Comment: what problem?if you don't post it how can people help you?you only posted the error relative to the strftime..I am guessing the problem relates to the nature of your data. you should let pople know how your data look like and a snippet demonstraating the problem